# Microsoft Excel Count when A=1 and B = 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Apologies in advance, as I am not sure how to phrase my question. Is there a way to determine how many times an event occurs based off of specific criteria? For example. In column A2:A5 the numbers 1,1,2,6,9 appears. In column B2:B5 the numbers 2,2,1,5,4 appears. What I would like to know is how many times a certain number appears in column B for a specific number in column A. So when the number in column A=1 how many times did the number 2 appear?

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. I used the count ifs function.

Comment: If you think it will be useful for others, can you answer your own question and mark it as correct? That way everyone will know it is resolved. If not, you can always delete the question